# SEO friendly rewrite and proper links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a hard time understanding how to rewrite and how to build links to achieve proper SEO friendly URLs, so far I have this:
.HTACCESS

```
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Let put all the rules we need...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Now lets build the rewrites...
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.html$ sy.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The index.html/php, just the basic
My links are like this

```
<a href="sy.php?id=1">Nice title one</a>
<a href="sy.php?id=2">Nice title two</a>
[...etc]
```

Now, i can make my links to be something like this

```
<a href="nice-title-one.html">Nice title one</a>
<a href="nice-title-two.html">Nice title two</a>
[...etc]
```

That is not a problem since I already have the "title" from the data base in that format I only add the ".html" at the end, but the problem is that is not working... what I want is that instead of http://foo.com/sy.php?id=1 be able to use http://foo.com/nice-title-one.html...
I did something like that with some similar approach but didn't had to use dynamic urls it was something basic like foo.com/contact, foo.com/portfolio...etc but for this I don't know how to build it... so if can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try to do something like this pattern. instead `site.com/sy.php?id=1` use `site.com/sy/title/1/`

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z]` does not match `nice-title-one`.

Comment: @Jimmer, yes, that way is working, the thing is that I'd like to hide the ID number... the new **RewriteRule** looks like this: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) sy.php?id=$1&t=$2 [NC,L]` and that is working